# what's the meaning of "for some time now"

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of "for some time now"

**for some time now**, the work of Italian philosopher Giorgio Agamben has been receiving growing attention and appreciation

Comment: It means _recently_, stretching back several years at least, in this context.

Comment: That for some immediate (a few years? months? days?) and measurable amount of time, his work has been recognized and appreciated as valuable, is what I would understand from the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

> **[for some time](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/time#for-some-time)** ~ for a long period of time
>   **[now](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/now)**
>   (sense 3) ~ used for saying how long it is since something happened or started

*"For some time now, ..."* in the sentence above means *"For a long (enough) period of time, ..."*. It's used for hinting that it's not something just happened yesterday. It's been as stated (in the sentence) for quite a while.

Comment: But it also indicates that the period in question continues to the present, and is used with a present perfect tense. Without the "now", and with other past tenses, it indicates a closed period in the past.